# C code crashes when run

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int line,linex;

    printf("Enter number of lines: ");
    scanf("%d",&line);
    linex=line;

    while(line!=0)
    {
        int input=0,total=0,number=0;

        printf("Enter line %d: ",(linex-line+1));
        scanf("%d",input);

        while (input!=-1)
        {
            total+=input;
            number++;
        }
        printf("Average = %f\n",(total/number));
        line-=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my code which will ask a user for the number of lines, the numbers in each line and then print out the average of each line. Thing is, when I try to run this in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 express, the program crashes. It crashes after I enter -1 to break the second WHILE loop.

Comment: As David wrote scanf needs the address of the variable input. BTW, your inner while loop will either be skipped or it will be entered and never left because `input!=-1` is loop invariant.

Comment: Aside from the crash, `total/number` is an integer, not a float, so you have undefined behavior there. Use `(float)total / number`, which converts `total` to a `float` so that floating point division is done (`total/(float)number` would work as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    scanf("%d",input);
```

Should be:

```
    scanf("%d",&input);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated, but

```
    while (input!=-1)
    {
        total+=input;
        number++;
    }
```

is an infinite loop. And if you enter -1 the first time then

```
 printf("Average = %f\n",(total/number));
```

is a division by zero. Both need to be fixed

Comment: "is a division by zero" Beyond that it's undefined behavior because it's an `int`, not a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

it is crashing because you  have forgotten to pass address to scanf function i.e. you have forgotten to write `&` at the time of scanf.
It must be

```
scanf("%d",&input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",input);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d",&input);
```

and check if `number != 0` before the division

```
printf("Average = %f\n",(total/number));
```

Answer (score 0):

crashing happens due to infinite loop

```
 while (input!=-1)   
 {    
        total+=input;
        number++;
 }
```

fixing this loop we do.

there are more potential bugs:

```
scanf("%d",input); //& missing

printf("Average = %f\n",(total/number)); // may cause divide by zero
```